# How to recreate SO posts with Django?

Tags: django, templates, orm

I am trying to recreate the comments section like SO. The original posts can have comments and answers, and the answers can have comment too. However, I don't know how to query the comments for the answers and show it in the template.

I have the following model.

```
class Post(Base):
    type_choices = (
        ('Q', 'Question'),
        ('A', 'Answer'),
        ('C', 'Comment'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                            choices=type_choices,
                            default='C')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    anonymous = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

For a particular post I can use the id as the `parent` value and fetch the answers and comments. But I can't fetch the comments for the answers.

Here is the view.

```
class PostView(DetailView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(type='Q')
    template_name = 'alpha/post.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['answers'] = Post.objects.filter(type='A', parent=self.object).order_by('-points', '-created')
        context['question_comments'] = Post.objects.filter(type='C', parent=self.object)
        return context
```

Comment: Regarding your original post, what do you mean you can't fetch the comments for answers? Can't you do `Post.objects.filter(type='C', parent__in=answers)`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your design makes much sense. You simply cannot have `Post` to represent 3 things. There are many attributes that don't belong to some of them, like a question/comment shouldn't have `accepted`, a comment shouldn't have `points`, etc.

I saw your `Post` is inheriting from `Base`, I assume that you are doing model inheritance. It's better to create `Question`, `Answer`, `Comment` as separate models and inherit from `Base`. It will make your code clearer and easier to read, you can certainly avoid doing `Post.objects.filter(type='C')` and having `parent` as well.

Here's a rough schema:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes        import generic

class Question(Base):
    # some other fields

class Answer(Base):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

class Comment(Base):
    post_ct = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    post_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    post = generic.GenericForeignKey('post_ct', 'post_id')
```

Then you do:

```
# create a comment tied to an answer
comment = Comment(post=answer)
comment.save()
# create a comment tied to a question
comment = Comment(post=question)
comment.save()
# get all comments for a question
question_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Question)
all_comments = Comment.objects.filter(post_ct=question_ct, post_id=question.id)
# get a post related to a comment
post = comment.post
```

[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Comment: Regardless of my model design you pointed out that comments are trickier. That's my question. How to loop through and display comments for the answers. Also parent field is required as it will tell us which answer the comment follows.